# Cmd+x halting the OSX keyboard

Tags: macos, keyboard, shortcut, numbers, keybindings

I have run into a very weird problem and any insight into this would be much appreciated. I noticed for the past two days whenever I press the <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd> keys into the keyboard to cut an entry in the numbers app, the entire keyboard stops functioning after that, in the sense that I can't type in any letter even anywhere with a text entry dialogue (like the address bar of the browser or another cell in the Numbers sheet).

I checked with the input menu from the keyboard in System Preferences that the system (macOS Catalina 10.15) does work. All key signals were correct but there was no effect on the other applications.

I feel it might be :

```
1. Some bug in Numbers app, but this is just too sudden!
2. I might have set some keyboard shortcut which makes this confusion happen.
```

If an expert can help me in this bizarre situation I would be grateful!

Edit: On the suggestion of @nohillside in the comments, I did an experiment to find out it isn't a numbers problem rather the keybinding <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd> currently does this behaviour. I tried cutting a link from the address bar and pasting into another address bar of another tab, I started facing the same issues.

So scratch my <s>1st</s> hunch. It isn't a Numbers app problem.

Comment: Does it only happen in one specific Numbers file or in all of them?

Comment: So i shall do an experiment and get back to you on this

Comment: I have updated based on your suggestion. The key combo makes the applications on the system not responsive to any other keys!

Comment: If it happens, what do you do to enable the keyboard again? Do you have any utilities/background apps running which intercept keyboard input? If you create a new user account on your Mac, does the problem occur there as well?

Comment: I do not have any app which runs to intercept the keyboard input. To enable the keyboard I restart the system. I didn't do the last suggestion, I might not be able to do with my current work constraints.

Comment: Ah, if this is a employer-provided Mac, maybe reach out to the support team?

Comment: No no it is my macbook itself, but i am currently on a deadline for some paper refereeing ( i am an academic ); so I need it to work perfectly till I'm done with my work. And I find myself always pressing on the key sequence to cut and then getting my system hung and do a force restart.